# Vectorised way to query date and price data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Question:**

Overview:

I'm looking for a vectorised way to get the first date that a certain condition is seen.  The condition is found when the price in `dfDays` is `>` the target price specified in `dfWeeks.target`.  This condition has to be hit after the date the target was set.

Is there a way to do the following time series analysis, with `apply` or similar, in a vectorised way in Pandas?

---

**Data:**

Generate `freq='D'` test dataframe

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '2000-07-31',freq='D')
weeks = np.random.uniform(low=1.03, high=3, size=(len(rng),))
ts2 = pd.Series(weeks
               ,index=rng)
dfDays = pd.DataFrame({'price':ts2})
```

Now create a resampled `freq='1W-Mon'` dataframe

```
dfWeeks = dfDays.resample('1W-Mon').first()
dfWeeks['target'] = (dfWeeks['price'] + .5).round(2)
```

Use `reindex` to align index on both df:

```
dfWeeks = dfWeeks.reindex(dfDays.index)
```

So `dfWeeks` is a dataframe containing the target values we will use

```
    dfWeeks.dropna().head()

               price    target
2000-01-03  1.851533    2.35
2000-01-10  1.625595    2.13
2000-01-17  1.855813    2.36
2000-01-24  2.130619    2.63
2000-01-31  2.756487    3.26
```

If we focus on the first target from `dfWeeks`

```
match = dfDays[dfDays.price >=  dfWeeks.target.loc['2000-01-03']]
```

The first match is in the past so not valid so the `2000-01-12` entry is the first valid match:

```
match.head()

            price
2000-01-02  2.449039
2000-01-12  2.379882
2000-01-14  2.759891
2000-01-16  2.350821
2000-01-21  2.607467
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this with `apply` or similar for `target` entries in `dfWeeks` in a vectorised way?

**Desired output:**

```
               price    target  target_hit
2000-01-03  1.851533    2.35    2000-01-12
2000-01-10  1.625595    2.13    2000-01-12 
2000-01-17  1.855813    2.36    2000-01-21
2000-01-24  2.130619    2.63    2000-01-25
2000-01-31  2.756487    3.26    nan
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic - how did you get `target` and `target_hit` columns in the desired data set

Comment: It looks to me like a ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/348814), when you are concentrating on that particular solution, whilst there might be a better ones. That is why i'm trying to understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: @Maxu, I updated the post with an overview of what I am trying  to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***`pandas`***

```
def find_match(x):
    match = dfDays.query('index > @x.name & price >= @x.target')
    if not match.empty:
        return match.index[0]

dfWeeks.assign(target_hit=dfWeeks.apply(find_match, 1))
```

***`numpy`***

```
timing = dfWeeks.index.values[:, None] < dfDays.index.values
target_hit = dfWeeks.target.values[:, None] <= dfDays.price.values
matches = timing & target_hit
got_match = matches.any(1)
first = matches.argmax(1)[got_match]

dfWeeks.loc[got_match, 'target_hit'] = dfDays.index.values[first]
dfWeeks
```

---

***both yield***

```
               price  target target_hit
2000-01-03  1.851533    2.35 2000-01-12
2000-01-10  1.625595    2.13 2000-01-12
2000-01-17  1.855813    2.36 2000-01-21
2000-01-24  2.130619    2.63 2000-01-25
2000-01-31  2.756487    3.26        NaT
2000-02-07  1.859582    2.36 2000-02-09
2000-02-14  1.066028    1.57 2000-02-15
2000-02-21  1.912350    2.41 2000-03-09
2000-02-28  1.446907    1.95 2000-02-29
2000-03-06  2.408524    2.91 2000-03-28
2000-03-13  2.337675    2.84 2000-03-17
2000-03-20  2.620561    3.12        NaT
2000-03-27  2.770113    3.27        NaT
2000-04-03  2.930735    3.43        NaT
2000-04-10  1.834030    2.33 2000-04-12
2000-04-17  2.068304    2.57 2000-04-19
2000-04-24  2.391067    2.89 2000-05-11
2000-05-01  2.518262    3.02        NaT
2000-05-08  1.085764    1.59 2000-05-10
2000-05-15  1.579992    2.08 2000-05-16
2000-05-22  2.619997    3.12        NaT
2000-05-29  1.269047    1.77 2000-05-31
2000-06-05  1.171789    1.67 2000-06-06
2000-06-12  2.175277    2.68 2000-06-20
2000-06-19  1.338879    1.84 2000-06-20
2000-06-26  2.977574    3.48        NaT
2000-07-03  1.160680    1.66 2000-07-04
2000-07-10  2.615366    3.12        NaT
2000-07-17  2.478080    2.98        NaT
2000-07-24  2.899562    3.40        NaT
2000-07-31  2.220492    2.72        NaT
```

Comment: I was going to leave this question for a couple of days then ask for your help if no response @piRSquared.  So lucky to have your help Sir!

Comment: Updated with a `numpy` approach as well.  Glad I could help

Comment: The `numpy` solution is very easy to implement on my real data.  Superb!

Comment: What does the '@x.name' represent please?

Comment: @ade1e when your use `query` you can access external variables with `'@'` so `'@x'` accesses the `x` variable.  `'@x.name'` grabs the name attribute of the x variable.

Comment: I think this will be useful to others as well so I have put this in a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922130/pandas-dataframe-query-method-syntax

Comment: How does the performance change for these? Could you add a %time for the operation as well. Il try to replicate it as well

Answer (score 2):

Just added a time for the queries. **Numpy** really shines here.

Could anyone confirm the findings by testing the same on their computer.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=1)
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '2000-07-31',freq='D')
weeks = np.random.uniform(low=1.03, high=3, size=(len(rng),))
ts2 = pd.Series(weeks
               ,index=rng)
dfDays = pd.DataFrame({'price':ts2})
dfWeeks = dfDays.resample('1W-Mon').first()
dfWeeks['target'] = (dfWeeks['price'] + .5).round(2)
```

**pandas**

```py
%%timeit
def find_match(x):
    match = dfDays.query('index > @x.name & price >= @x.target')
    if not match.empty:
        return match.index[0]

dfWeeks.assign(target_hit=dfWeeks.apply(find_match, 1))
```

`10 loops, best of 3: 66 ms per loop`

**numpy**

```py
%timeit
timing = dfWeeks.index.values[:, None] < dfDays.index.values
target_hit = dfWeeks.target.values[:, None] <= dfDays.price.values
matches = timing & target_hit
got_match = matches.any(1)
first = matches.argmax(1)[got_match]

dfWeeks.loc[got_match, 'target_hit'] = dfDays.index.values[first]
dfWeeks
```

The slowest run took 4.10 times longer than the fastest. This could 
mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
`1000 loops, best of 3: 999 µs per loop`