# Pandas dataframe.query method syntax

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:**

I would like to gain a better understanding of the Pandas [DataFrame.query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method and what the following expression represents:

```
match = dfDays.query('index > @x.name & price >= @x.target')
```

What does `@x.name` represent?

I understand what the resulting output is for this code (a new column with `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` data) but don't have a clear understanding of the expression used to get this end result.

**Data:**

From here:

[Vectorised way to query date and price data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909097/vectorised-way-to-query-date-and-price-data/41910327?noredirect=1#comment71008239_41910327)

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '2000-07-31',freq='D')
weeks = np.random.uniform(low=1.03, high=3, size=(len(rng),))
ts2 = pd.Series(weeks
               ,index=rng)
dfDays = pd.DataFrame({'price':ts2})
dfWeeks = dfDays.resample('1W-Mon').first()
dfWeeks['target'] = (dfWeeks['price'] + .5).round(2)

def find_match(x):
    match = dfDays.query('index > @x.name & price >= @x.target')
    if not match.empty:
        return match.index[0]

dfWeeks.assign(target_hit=dfWeeks.apply(find_match, 1))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything @MaxU said is perfect!

I wanted to add some context to the specific problem that this was applied to.

## `find_match`

This is a helper function that is used in the dataframe `dfWeeks.apply`.  Two things to note:

1. `find_match` takes a single argument `x`.  This will be a single row of `dfWeeks`.

   - Each row is a `pd.Series` object and each row will be passed through this function.  This is the nature of using `apply`.
   - When `apply` passes this row to the helper function, the row has a `name` attribute that is equal to the index value for that row in the dataframe.  In this case, I know that the index value is a `pd.Timestamp` and I'll use it to do the comparing I need to do.
2. `find_match` references `dfDays` which is outside the scope of `find_match` itself.

I didn't have to use `query`... I like using `query`.  It is my opinion that it makes some code prettier.  The following function, as provided by the OP, could've been written differently

```
def find_match(x):
    """Original"""
    match = dfDays.query('index > @x.name & price >= @x.target')
    if not match.empty:
        return match.index[0]

dfWeeks.assign(target_hit=dfWeeks.apply(find_match, 1))
```

## `find_match_alt`

Or we could've done this, which may help to explain what the `query` string is doing above

```
def find_match_alt(x):
    """Alternative to OP's"""
    date_is_afterwards = dfDays.index > x.name
    price_target_is_met = dfDays.price >= x.target
    both_are_true = price_target_is_met & date_is_afterwards
    if (both_are_true).any():
        return dfDays[both_are_true].index[0]

dfWeeks.assign(target_hit=dfWeeks.apply(find_match_alt, 1))
```

---

Comparing these two functions should give good perspective.

Comment: Great explanation, exactly what I was looking for.  I wish I could upvote it more than once!

Comment: Very neat answer!

Answer (score 11):

`@x.name` - `@` helps `.query()` to understand that `x` is an external object (doesn't belong to the DataFrame for which the query() method was called). In this case `x` is a DataFrame. It could be a scalar value as well.

I hope this small demonstration will help you to understand it:

```
In [79]: d1
Out[79]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [80]: d2
Out[80]:
   a   x
0  1  10
1  7  11

In [81]: d1.query("a in @d2.a")
Out[81]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  7  8  9

In [82]: d1.query("c < @d2.a")
Out[82]:
   a  b  c
1  4  5  6
```

Scalar `x`:

```
In [83]: x = 9

In [84]: d1.query("c == @x")
Out[84]:
   a  b  c
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: For `d1.query("c < @d2.a")` I got `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.